# Convert pixel data back to image in Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have a code that puts an image in a pixel matrix.I have to split this image into four parts and get 4 different image files for these parts.
Then I have to do some image processing on it and then join those parts back together in a single image.
Please help me in achieving this.
Note:the image is colored and we want to just split it into 4 equal parts and then get it back as one.No changes needed.Here is the code to get four matrices of intensities.But I don't know what to do with it.It might be that there is no need of it at all.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    class Optimization
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
   {

      BufferedImage hugeImage = ImageIO.read(new File("comp.jpg"));
        final byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) hugeImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
     int width = hugeImage.getWidth();
     int height = hugeImage.getHeight();
      if(width%2!=0)
          width=width-1;
      if(height%2!=0)
         height=height-1;
      //System.out.print(width+" "+height);
     int intensity[][]=new int[width][height];
     int b1[][]=new int[width/2][height/2];
     int b2[][]=new int[width/2][height/2];
     int b3[][]=new int[width/2][height/2];
     int b4[][]=new int[width/2][height/2];
     int x1=0,y1=0,x2=0,y2=0,x3=0,x4=0,y3=0,y4=0;
      final int pixelLength = 3;
         for (int pixel = 0, row = 0, col = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel += pixelLength) 
            {
            int a1,a2,a3;
           a3= ((int) pixels[pixel] & 0xff); // blue
           a2= (((int) pixels[pixel + 1] & 0xff)); // green
           a1= (((int) pixels[pixel + 2] & 0xff)); // red
            int i=(a1+a2+a3)/3;
            intensity[col][row]=i;
            if((col<=width/2-1)&&(row<=height/2-1))
            {
                b1[x1][y1]=i;
                x1++;
                if(col==width/2-1)
                {
                    x1=0;
                    y1++;
                }
            }
            if((col<width)&&(row<=height/2-1)&&(col>width/2-1))
            {
                b2[x2][y2]=i;
                x2++;
                if(col==width-1)
                {
                    x2=0;
                    y2++;
                }
            }
            if((col<width/2)&&(row<height)&&(row>=height/2))
            {
                b3[x3][y3]=i;
                x3++;
                if(col==width/2-1)
                {
                    x3=0;
                    y3++;
                }
            }
            if((col>width/2-1)&&(row>height/2-1))
            {
                b4[x4][y4]=i;
                x4++;
                if(col==width-1)
                {
                    x4=0;
                    y4++;
                }
            }
            col++;
            if (col == width)
            {
               col = 0;
               row++;   

            }

    }
     for(int m=0;m<height/2;m++)
     {
         for(int n=0;n<width/2;n++)
         {
             System.out.print(b1[n][m]+" ");
         }
         System.out.println();
     }



   }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what you are trying to do.  Please show some examples.

Comment: Just want to split an image into four parts.That's it.

Comment: Does your code work? Does it fail? Have you stepped through it in your debugger to see where it deviates from what you expect?  If it fails, what is the wrong  behavior? Is there an exception? If so, show us the stack trace and tell us where in your code the exception originates.  You have to help us to help you.

Comment: My code works completely fine.no error at all.I have split the image data array into four parts.Now I want to know what to do next to turn this data back to four different images.

Comment: Then what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

`java.awt.Image` provides you `getSubimage(int x, int y, int w, int h)`

"Returns a subimage defined by a specified rectangular region." You just return four equal regions and thats it.

Comment: That's a good way indeed.But what if I want to join those parts of sub image back after processing?

Comment: @Srijan Then you mention it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getSubImage(int x, int y, int w, int h)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), but you will get an image that shares the same raster than the original image, meaning that if you modify the new sub-image, then you also modify the original image. If it's not problematic for you, then use it.

Else, as you have already accessed the DataBuffer (good idea), here is a simple code to do what you want (I just make DataBuffer copies, and it works when the image dimensions are odd):

```
BufferedImage image = ... ;
BufferedImage q1 = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/2, image.getType()) ;
BufferedImage q2 = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth()-image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/2, image.getType()) ;
BufferedImage q3 = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()-image.getHeight()/2, image.getType()) ;
BufferedImage q4 = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth()-image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()-image.getHeight()/2, image.getType()) ;
byte[] bb = ((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;
byte[] bbq1 = ((DataBufferByte)q1.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;
byte[] bbq2 = ((DataBufferByte)q2.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;
byte[] bbq3 = ((DataBufferByte)q3.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;
byte[] bbq4 = ((DataBufferByte)q4.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;

for (int y=0 ; y < q1.getHeight() ; y++) // Fill Q1 and Q2
    {
    System.arraycopy(bb, y*image.getWidth(), bbq1, y*q1.getWidth(), q1.getWidth()) ;
    System.arraycopy(bb, y*image.getWidth()+q1.getWidth(), bbq2, y*q2.getWidth(), q2.getWidth()) ;
    }

for (int y=0 ; y < q3.getHeight() ; y++) // Fill Q3 and Q4
    {
    System.arraycopy(bb, (y+q1.getHeight())*image.getWidth(), bbq3, y*q3.getWidth(), q3.getWidth()) ;
    System.arraycopy(bb, (y+q1.getHeight())*image.getWidth()+q3.getWidth(), bbq4, y*q4.getWidth(), q4.getWidth()) ;
    }
```

Comment: That's mind blowing logic to create separate byte arrays that won't affect the original image.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to join back all the parts of image after some image processing on it?

Comment: You do exactly the opposite of the code I've shared. You create a big image equal to the sum of the four images, then you add one line/row of Q1, followed by 1 line/row of Q2, until Q1/Q2 are completely copied. Then you start adding Q3/Q4 the same way.

Comment: This code is either not working fine or I am not able to figure out how to join the image back.Can you help me?

Comment: This code works fine to decompose an image, but you have to modify it (as I said into my previous comment) if you want to recompose the quadrants into an image.

Comment: I tried but was not able to figure out.Request you to help me in the same. This link has some code but this does not work for me.         http://ideone.com/WpKfnJ